# if $x-y =\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}$ with $x\neq y$ then $(1+\frac{1}{x})(1+\frac{1}{y})\geq 25$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

let $x\neq y$ be positive real numbers such that :$x-y= \sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}$ , I have tried to prove this inequality $(1+\frac{1}{x})(1+\frac{1}{y})\geq 25$ that i have created but i didn't got it.

**Attempt** I have showed that:$(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y})\geq \frac{2}{\sqrt{xy}}$ using this identity:  $(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2\geq0$ , I also showed that :$\frac{1}{xy}\geq \frac{1}{16}$ , Now I have used both result I have got the following inequality :$(1+\frac{y}{x})(1+\frac{x}{y})\geq 25$ but not what i have claimed , any way ?

Comment: I am missing something or the inequality is false for $x =y=1$ whike the equality is true?

Comment: If $x=y=1$, $x-y=\sqrt x-\sqrt y$, but $(1+{1\over x})(1+{1\over y})=4$, which is not greater than or equal to 25.

Comment: Tkae $\;x=y=1\;$ as an easy counter example....

Comment: If you omit $x=y$ as solutions, then your condition is equivalent to $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=1$.

Comment: Thanks i missed that i have edited it now it fixed

Comment: If $x\ne y$ then as @CheerfulParsnip said, $\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{y}$, so you can take $x=\sin^4 t$ and $y=\cos^4t$ for some $t$

Comment: @TitoEliatron you mean $\sqrt x+\sqrt y=1$

Comment: Yes, of course. Sorry

Comment: Should be a way of doing it with just normal inequalities, but calculus also works: study the function $f(x) = (1+\frac{1}{x^2})(1+\frac{1}{(1-x)^2})$ on $[0,1]$. By computing $f'(x)$ show that the minimum is at $x=1/2$ and then $f(1/2) = 25$ gives the result.

Comment: If you take $\sqrt{x} = \frac{1+a}{2} + a$ and $\sqrt{y} = \frac{1-b}{2}$ then the condition becomes $a = b$ with $a\in (-1,1)$ and substituting this into the expression you end up with a simple inequality that is easy to check.

Comment: As $x\ne y$ the inequality is strict.

Answer (score 9):

Following the hints of the comments, your condition implies that 
$$\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} = 1$$
AM-GM states 
$$1 \geq 2\sqrt{\sqrt{xy}} \implies 1/4 \geq \sqrt{xy}$$
Use Cauchy on
$$(1+1/x)(1+1/y) \geq (1+1/\sqrt{xy})^2$$
Pluggin in what you got in the AM-GM for $\sqrt{xy}$,
$$\geq (1+ 4)^2 =25$$

Answer (score 1):

Just to give a different approach, let $x=1/u^2$ and $y=1/v^2$ with $u,v\gt0$. Then

$$\begin{align}
x-\sqrt x=y-\sqrt y
&\implies{1\over u^2}-{1\over v^2}={1\over u}-{1\over v}\\
&\implies{(v-u)(v+u)\over u^2v^2}={v-u\over uv}\\
&\implies{v+u\over uv}=1\\
&\implies{1\over u}+{1\over v}=1
\end{align}$$

provided $u\not=v$ (i.e., provided $x\not=y$), which allows the cancellation of the $v-u$ term. Note this now requires $u,v\gt1$. We also have

$${v+u\over uv}=1\implies uv=u+v\implies u^2v^2=(v+u)^2=u^2+v^2+2uv=u^2+v^2+2u+2v$$

It follows that

$$\begin{align}
\left(1+{1\over x}\right)\left(1+{1\over y}\right)
&=(1+u^2)(1+v^2)\\
&=1+u^2+v^2+u^2v^2\\
&=1+2u^2+2v^2+2u+2v\\
&={(2u+1)^2+(2v+1)^2\over2}\\
&\gt{(2\cdot1+1)^2+(2\cdot1+1)^2\over2}\\
&=25
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

The function
$$y\mapsto \log\left(1+\tfrac{1}{y^2}\right)$$
is convex on $(0,\infty)$, so Jensen's inequality
$$\mathrm{E}\left[\,\log\left(1+\tfrac{1}{Y^2}\right)\right]\geq \log\left(1+\tfrac{1}{\mathrm{E}[Y]^2}\right)$$
holds for any positive random variable $Y$. Letting $Y=\sqrt{X}$, in particular we have
$$\mathrm{E}\left[\,\log\left(1+\tfrac{1}{X}\right)\right]\geq \log\left(1+\tfrac{1}{\mathrm{E}[\sqrt{X}]^2}\right)$$
for any positive random variable $X$.

Now, let $X$ be a categorical variable taking on the $N$ positive values $x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{N-1}$ with equal probability $\tfrac{1}{N}$, and suppose that
$$\mathrm{E}[\sqrt{X}]=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\sqrt{x_i}=\frac{1}{N}\text{.}$$
Then the inequality above is

$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\log\left(1+\tfrac{1}{x_i}\right)\geq \log(1+N^2)\text{;}$$
taking exponentials, we have shown that
$$\boxed{\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\sqrt{x_i}=1\Rightarrow\prod_{i=0}^{N-1}\left(1+\tfrac{1}{x_i}\right)\geq (1+N^2)^N }\text{.}$$
OP's inequality is the case $N=2$.

Answer (score 0):

By AM-GM
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)=\left(1+\frac{4}{4x}\right)\left(1+\frac{4}{4y}\right)\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{5}{\sqrt[5]{(4x)^4}}\cdot\frac{5}{\sqrt[5]{(4y)^4}}=\frac{25}{\sqrt[5]{4^{8}\left(\sqrt{xy}\right)^8}}\geq\frac{5}{\sqrt[5]{4^8\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}{2}\right)^{16}}}=25.$$